# Unable to get correct values after json parse

Tags: jquery, json

This is my code where I populating data into template by cloning it within for loop.

```
$('.menu li').on('click', function() {

        var templateName = $('.template-list');

        var template = [];
        var data = [];

        for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

             template = $(templateName).removeClass('hidden').clone();

             $(template).find('[data-image] img').attr('src', 'http://via.placeholder.com/350x200');
             $(template).find('[data-type]').html('cosmetic product');
             $(template).find('[data-price]').html('$30');
             $(template).find('[data-title]').html('Beauty cafe');
             $(template).find('[data-desc]').html('stry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry\'s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetti');

            data.push(template);

        }

        $('#list').append(data);//this works correctly, I don't want to append on the same page.

    });
```

The above code works, as it gets cloned template, pushed to array called data and append the result into same page div with ID #list.

But what I intend to do is, to append the result on another page.

To retain the value across pages, I use `sessionStorage`.
So,

```
sessionStorage.setItem('result', JSON.stringify(data));
location.replace('redirect to another page here);
```

while on another page,

var data2 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('result')); //i do get the string parsed here back into array of objects but the data doesn't seem to have retained.

//below throws error saying, data not in context

```
for (var i = 0; i< total; i++) {
    console.debug(data[i]);
    $('#list').append(data[i]);
}
```

I debug this way:

```
 1)  console.debug(data);
    sessionStorage.setItem('result', JSON.stringify(data));
```

The result for 1) is:
[image]

```
 2) var data2 = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('result'));
    console.debug(data2);
```

The result for 2) is:
[image]

The result shows what the result contains when I click any of the array object before and after json.parse.

Comment: You can't store DOM elements as JSON. You also can't store jQuery objects as JSON, because they contain functions and DOM elements, and there's no JSON represntation for those.

Comment: @Barmar, i see, is there any other way I can shift these type of data via browser cookies then

Comment: You can't store DOM elements in any permanent way, they contain dynamic information. You should store the raw data that you use to construct the DOM elements.